# Minimization of Frobenius norm with nuclear norm penalization

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, nuclear-norm

Define $\mathcal{M}_n$ and $\mathcal{S}_n$ as the space of $n\times n$ real matrices and $n\times n$ symmetric real matrices, respectively. I want to solve the problem 
$$
\min_{A\in S_n}\frac{1}{2}\|A-Q\|_F^2+\lambda\|A\|_*, \quad (1)
$$
where $Q\in S_n$, $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm and $\|\cdot\|_*$ the nuclear norm.

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.3286.pdf) it is proved that 
$$
D_{\lambda}(Q) = \text{argmin}_{A\in \mathcal{M}_n}\frac{1}{2}\|A-Q\|_F^2+\lambda\|A\|_*,
$$
where 
$$
D_{\lambda}(Q) = U\text{diag}((\sigma_i-\lambda)_{+})V^T,\quad (2)
$$
where $Q = U\text{diag}(\sigma_i)V^T$ is the SVD of $Q$.

My problem is that I want to minimize over $\mathcal{S}_n$ and not $\mathcal{M}_n$, and the solution $D_{\lambda}(Q)$ is not symmetric at least $Q$ is semi-positive definite.

Is there a way to use the result (2) in my problem? Or I should use another method to solve (1)?

Comment: Can you explain what is $D_{\lambda}(A)$? I don't see why is it even a function of $A$? I mean we have a argmin in the RHS

Comment: @ShivTavker Sure. It should be $D_{\lambda}(Q)$, it's a typo.

Comment: $D_\lambda(Q)$ is the prox operator associated to the nuclear norm. It is the $\ell^1$ prox applied to the singular values.

Comment: Since $Q$ is symmetric, $V=U$ in the SVD decomposition. Therefore $D_\lambda$ is symmetric.

Comment: @greg That is not true. Take Q=diag(1,-1). U=V when Q>=0.

Comment: @RLC Good point. The SVD factors are not _identical_  but rather their columns are (up to an overall sign), i.e. $\,u_k=\pm v_k\;$ However, this is enough to ensure that the matrix in question is symmetric, since $\,D_\lambda=\sum \beta_ku_ku_k^T$

Comment: @greg Thanks! I don't know how I couldn't see that since diagonal matrices are commutative (what I mean: $Q=PDP^T=P|D|\text{sign}(D)P^T=P\text{sign}(D)|D|P^T$).